# Python cycle through list of dicts to find attributes

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've got a complex JSON stucture which has been loaded into a dict:

```
{
  "assets": [
    { 
      "account": "Prod",
      "distributiongroups": [],
      "name": "Admin",
      "networks": [
        { 
        ...
        },
    { 
       "account": "Dev",
       "distributiongroups": []
    ...
```

I'd like to get a list of all account names, my problem is that with

```
accounts = data['assets'][0]['name']
```

I just get the first account, is there any simple way to cycle through all list items without writing a long loop? Something like

```
accounts = data['assets'][0:]['name']
```

Comment: take a look at dpath https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dpath could be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to build a new list from a loop:

```
accounts = [account['name'] for account in data['assets']]
```

This takes the `'name'` value for each dictionary in the list referenced by `data['assets']`.